# How can I create a shared string over the internet which is accessible through different C# Web Apps?

Tags: c#, azure

Two programs want to talk to one another. They both need some way to address one another. The addresses are two strings I've stored in a common location (on cloud, perhaps), which allows them to talk to one another.

Now, I have access to Azure services and I can easily create a dummy database table which will contain this entry, and I'll set the value from one program, access it from the other using SQL queries.

Is there a more elegant solution? I don't need to store any special objects, just a simple string.

The limitation here is, I cannot do socket message passing because it isn't my intention to 'wait' for the message. The programs have other things to be doing, and they will periodically check this shared string, if it is not null they will talk to the address in the string. If it is null, they carry on with whatever they were doing.

I'm trying to abstract away the notion of 'address' in this question, intentionally, since I'm not looking to solve the larger problem of designing the programs. Only the specific issue of the shared string object.

Comment: This is a really broad and opinion-soliciting question with no single "right" answer. And certainly no "easiest to program" or "fastest possible solution" for this (just consider the many programming languages, databases, etc. available). This might be a good discussion on a blog or forum, but it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Fair enough. What if I remove that qualifier of 'easiest' or 'fastest', and simply wanted one (any) workable solution? (Also I've restricted the programming language to C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify any non functional requirements in terms of scalability, performance, etc.  There are probably 1000s of ways to do this, using SQL Azure is one.

This kind of thing (shared state) is usually handled by a distributed cache service (in Azure the recommended one is Redis cache), which would be faster than SQL Azure.

You could also go for Service Fabric clusters with persisted state that would be replicated between nodes - overkill for a string, but I don't think that's probably your end game?

You can then also use queues and subscriptions, Azure Storage queues or Servicebus - depending on how you wanted the messages to flow or get/set updates.

You could also use a storage account (Blobs, Tables, File Share) to share the data in.  Think Ill stop there unless you narrow down the requirements a little!

Answer (score -1):

If you want a hack but quick solution, try DropBox.  Create a public area with access Url and put a shared file there. [See here for more details.](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/16)